# get job/workflow status out of Control M?

Tags: control-m

I am new to Control M and would like to find out if status of jobs/workflows can be queried programmatically.

I am trying to see if I can get :
job schedule, what jobs are waiting to be run,
status of each job, waiting, complete, in process..etc

Can I query the Control M somehow and get these info on demand?

I read some where that BMC Control-M Business Process Integration Suite provides something similar.
Can someone tell me if this is possible?
Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

You can do that through Keystroke Language programs.
If you go to 3.4 and do a search by BMC.IOA.**.KSL, in the resultant libraries search for REPJOBSA.
This will give you something like:

```
JOBa     CTMXXX   ODATE                    JOB Wait Schedule   
JOBb     CTMXXX   ODATE  JOBNAMEB/JOBIDb   JOB Ended "Not OK"
JOBc     CMXXXX   ODATE                    JOB Wait Schedule    
JOBy     CTMXXX   ODATE  JOBNAMEY/JOBIDy   JOB Ended "OK"
```

Then, with a SORT you can format the output.

Example of the STEP to get the previous information:

```
//A01TEP   EXEC IOARKSL,COND=(00,NE)               
  TRACE OFF                                        
  MAXCOMMAND 999999                                
  CALLMEM REPJOBST                                 
  END                                              
//DAKSLREP DD DSN=FILENAME,      
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),             
//            SPACE=(TRK,(xx,yy),RLSE),            
//            DCB=(RECFM=dd,LRECL=lll)
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic access to Control-M is provided as a standard part of the product since V9. You can use RESTful web service requests either directly or via a node.js cli called "CTM". You should be able to find lots of dicumentaiton by entering Contorl-M Automation API into you favorite search engine.